# Why am I not able to press the button on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

I have a button that I need displayed on top of another element in React Native. I have given the button a position of "absolute" and a flex: 1, and it works and looks beautiful on android, but on iOS, it doesn't let the user click the button. Is there something I am missing?

The element that the button needs to be on top of is a video player, which the user also needs to be able to click to pause/play.

Here are the elements:

```
 <VideoPlayer
          shouldPlay={true}
          useNativeControls={true}
          resizeMode={"contain"}
          source={{
            uri:
              "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4",
          }}
          style={styles.video}
        />
        <View style={styles.exitButton}>
          <ExitButton onPress={backNavigation} />
        </View>
```

Here are the styles:

```
  exitButton: {
    position: "absolute",
    alignItems: "flex-end",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%",
    paddingBottom: 250
  },
  video: {
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
    flex: 2
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

`zIndex` will help you to add your button on top of the current layer.
You can give any positive number in index.

Also, add some `height` as well. As if you have a smaller image, then its very small touchable area.

You can get more info on this [document](https://docs.expo.dev/ui-programming/z-index/).

```
exitButton: {
    position: "absolute",
    alignItems: "flex-end",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    height: 50,
    width: "100%",
    paddingBottom: 250
  },
```

Comment: Adding a height to the button changes the size of the video, so I don't want to do this. Also zIndex does not work.

Comment: Possible to share your entire code

Comment: This is client work, so I can only share what I already have.